# Regex match sentence Java

Tags: java, regex

Need regex for matching sentence by single word

Sentence:

> "The following program, IfElseDemo, " +
>                   "assigns a grade based on the value of a test score: " +
>                   "an A for a score of 90% or above, a B for a score of 80% or             above, and so on"

Pattern word: `IfElseDemo`

Tryed: `"[^.]* IfElseDemo,\\s [^.]*"` but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: what's the result desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `/.*IfElseDemo.*/g`

You can check this [here](http://regexr.com/3d4t2)